# How to add css text color value from php variable that get value from user input label

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I created WP plugin that add free shipping badge under price on product if price higher then some limited price that user post. I wanna add option that user can change color of text on badge. This is how i do it, but its doesn`t work. I hope i get some help here. Any advice please?

The plugin admin screenshoot:

[image: plugin admin screenshoot]

The code:

```
/** ADD FREE SHIPPING BADGE SUFFIX AFTER PRICE **/
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_suffix', 'fsb_suffix', 99, 4 );
function fsb_suffix( $html, $product, $price, $qty ){
    $fsb_price = (float) $product->get_price(); // Regular price
    $fsb_limit_price = esc_attr( get_option('fsb_limit_price_option') ); // Limit price
    $fsb_badge_text = esc_attr( get_option('fsb_badge_text_option') ); // Text to display on badge
    $fsb_badge_text_color = esc_attr( get_option('fsb_badge_text_color_option') ) ; // Text Color to display on badge
    if(!empty($fsb_limit_price) && $fsb_price >= $fsb_limit_price){
        $html .='</br>'.'<fsb_badge class="fsb_badge_view" style="color:<?php echo $fsb_badge_text_color?>">' .$fsb_badge_text.' '.'</fsb_badge>';
        return $html;
    }
}
```

Any help or advice is appreciated.

Comment: `$fsb_badge_text_color` is missing `;`

Comment: I try add it, but still not work